What is the true meaning of the word "appeared" in scripture?
My question is actually a follow up question on a related question I asked on Christianity Stack Exchange. In Matt 27:52-53 it is written that these saints rose from the dead and appeared to many in Jerusalem:
Mathew 27:52-53 (NIV):

... [they] went into the holy city [Jerusalem] and appeared to many people.

In focusing on the meaning of the word "appeared", I then tried to find other instances where the same word was used and got these verses in the book of Judges:

Judges 6:12 (NIV):

When the angel of the LORD appeared to Gideon, he said, “The LORD is with you, mighty warrior.”


Judges 13:3 (NIV):

The angel of the LORD appeared to her and said, “You are barren and childless, but you are going to become pregnant and give birth to a son.



Does the word "appear" mean "to suddenly manifest in the physical world from the spirit world?", since some contributors tried to say the word "appear" has been used to mean that those saints rose from their graves, walked up to Jerusalem and met normal men. If that is the case then why wouldn't scripture phrased it like "they went up to Jerusalem and met with their other men?"

emphanizo see Biblehub means to inform, to declare, or to present oneself to the sight of another. The meaning you are trying to force is not there. The word is used ten times in scripture.

@NigelJ, but why would the meaning be different in the context of the resurrection of the saints?

@GratefulDisciple, thanks for the edit. The post is more coherent now.

For hermeneutical clarity, it's important to take into account many factors, including the historical semantic range of a word in question in context. For example, I love ice cream, I love my wife, and I love to discover evidence that provides a better perspective on historical writings or events. The word, 'love," somehow encompasses all of my responses, but the definitions of this word shouldn't be blurred together. Capiche?

@Dieter, you may be right but how can we be sure the appeared does not convey the same meaning as the passages in the book of Judges?

It's context and word choice. Also note that Judges was written in Hebrew, but Matthew was written in Greek. The Hebrew uses the same word for "appeared" (SG7200, ra'ah, to see) in Judges 6 and 13, also the LXX uses the same Greek word for "appeared" in both Judges 6 and 13, BUT in Matthew 27, the Greek word is "revealed" (SG1718 ), which has a different meaning than appeared. Hope this helps.

I see that the OP's question on C.se [What happened to the multitude Jesus raised immediately he rose from the dead?] was was closed but perhaps we can shed light on it here using objective biblical data and hermeneutical principles. In so doing I hope also to answer the question about what is meant by "appeared."
First, we should be aware that although the text says "the bodies of many saints who had fallen asleep were raised" it does not state that these were mere physical bodies. On the other hand we learn from St. Paul that a physical body is very different from a resurrected "spiritual body."

40 There are both heavenly bodies and earthly bodies, but the
brightness of the heavenly is one kind and that of the earthly
another. 41 The brightness of the sun is one kind, the brightness of
the moon another, and the brightness of the stars another. For star
differs from star in brightness. 42 So also is the resurrection of
the dead. It is sown corruptible; it is raised incorruptible. 43 It is
sown dishonorable; it is raised glorious. It is sown weak; it is
raised powerful. 44 It is sown a natural body; it is raised a
spiritual body.

Thus, although @Dottard is quite right to say that "these resurrected people were not disembodied ghosts" we also should not think of them as mere reanimated corpses. Paul likens their light to the sun, moon and stars in comparison to normal, physical bodies. Their appearance, as resurrected spiritual bodies, must have been brilliant those who "had eyes to see."  To some, however, they may have remained invisible, just as the resurrected Jesus was not visible to the men who accompanied Paul in Acts 9, who could hear Jesus but not see him.
This enables us to address the question of what happened to them. I suggest that, just as Jesus ascended the heaven after a period of ministry on earth, so these OT saints ascended into another realm, such as "Paradise," which is the realm reached by one one of the men crucified with Jesus (Luke 23:43) as well as the realm that Paul apparently glimpsed in 2 Corinthians 12:4.
Conclusion: "Appears" means that they became visible to those who were capable of seeing. But their brilliance would have been blinding to others, who may not have actually recognized them.  The OT saints who thus appeared, soon ascended to Paradise.

Why would these resurrected persons have had different bodies than, for instance, the widow's son whom Elijah resurrected or Lazarus, who should have been stinking by then?

Well answered upvoted and accepted , very authoritative and clear.

@MikeBorden...  The body of the widow's son was what Paul calls a "natural body" that simply lived out its normal physical life. The spiritual bodies of the OT saints described here apparently ascended to Paradise or Heaven. Of course, there are various opinions as to whether a "spiritual body" is merely a glorified physical body or a distinct entity that ascends to the spiritual realm while the physical body disintegrates.

So these Old Testament saints that we're talking about received their Resurrection bodies before Jesus did? How can Jesus be the first fruits if that is the case?

The verb ἐμφανίζω (emphanizó) is used 10 times in the NT.  According to BDAG, it has the following three meanings:

to lay open to view, make visible, eg, John 14:22, Matt 27:53, Heb 9:24
to provide information, make clear, explain, inform, make a report, eg, Acts 23:15, 32, Heb 11;14, John 14:21
to convey a formal report about a judicial matter, present evidence, bring charges, Acts 24:1, 25:2, 15.

Now, it is useless to ask why the Scripture does not express things the way I think they should be said.  The Bible is the inspired word of God (2 Tim 3:16, 17, 2 Peter 1:21) and thus the words selected are just what they should be.
In the case of Matt 27:52, 53 we have a simple record of the following:

The tombs broke open,
and the bodies of many saints who had fallen asleep were raised.
After Jesus’ resurrection, when they had come out of the tombs, they entered the holy city and appeared to many people.

Note that this records a bodily resurrection - these resurrected people were not disembodied ghosts.  Further, they did not suddenly appear but they:

came out of their tombs
entered the holy city (Jerusalem)
appeared to many people

That is, as they walked about the city, they encountered many people who recognized them.  There is nothing uncomplicated about this simple narrative.
There is a similar meaning in John 14:22 without any suggestion of "suddenly appearing from nothing" -

Judas (not Iscariot) asked Him, “Lord, why are You going to reveal
Yourself to us and not to the world?”

The same is true of Heb 9:24 -

For Christ did not enter a man-made copy of the true sanctuary, but He
entered heaven itself, now to appear on our behalf in the presence
of God.

LXX
Note that the verb in Judges 6:12 is ὤφθη which is a form of ὁράω - a quite different verb from that above.  The same verb ὁράω is also used in Judges 13:3 as well.  This verb means to "see, look upon, experience, perceive, discern, beware." (Strong's)

+1 Great! This seems to portend that the intended meaning of the verb ἐμφανίζω (emphanizó) is explained in verses 52 and 53. Can the narrative part of Jesus's journey with the two disciples to emmaeus be similar to this narrative? Jesus walked with them but dissappeared after breaking bread. Do you think these saints experienced the same afterall they also resurrected? If Jesus's and these saints ressurection are similar (minus the spectacular), could they have expressed similar behaviour like that of Jesus?

@BOAVINTURAFERREIRA, exactly my point. Thanks for your input and shared perspective on this matter.

@BOAVINTURAFERREIRA - first the verb you are interested in does not appear in Luke 24 anywhere.  The only relevant word is the adjective ἄφαντος (disappeared) from the cognate root φαίνω, again a different verb.

I think there is a verse that actually says, Jesus appeared to the twelve, how do you reconcile that?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany - 1 Cor 15:5 says, "and that he appeared to Cephas, and then to the Twelve.".  Again, the verb is ὁράω - different from what your question askes about.

Is it the same word used in Mat 27:52-53?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany - please read my answer - I have listed ALL the instances of the verb emphanizó in the answer and this includes Matt 27:53.  That verb in Matt 27 is DIFFERNT from ὁράω that is used in 1 Cor 15.  Please at least read what I have written.

Since you mentioned the angel of the Lord at Judges 6:12 and Judges 13:3 how can it be determined whether his appearance is physical, a vision, or in a dream. For instance at Genesis 15:1, "After these things the word of the Lord came to Abraham in a vision." It should also be noted that God has appeared in visions in the Bible which means the person is actually seeing something. One example is Moses saw the burning bush at Exodus 3:2, the angel of the Lord.
Now, the angel of the Lord appeared to Hagar at Genesis 16:7. He said He would multiply her descendants, vs10. At vs11 He told her she shall have a son and his name will be Ishmael. Today his descendants are the Arabs.
At vs13 Hagar says, "Then she called the name of the Lord who spoke to her, "Thou art a God who sees": for she said, "Have I even remained alive here after seeing Him?" Now we come to Genesis 17:1-3,
Now we come to Genesis 17:1-3, Now when Abram was ninety-nine years old, the Lord APPEARED to Abram and said to him, "I am God Almighty; Walk before Me and be blameless. vs2, And I will establish My covenant between Me and you, And I will multiply you exceedingly." Vs3, "And Abram fell on his face, and God talked with him saying," So how can it be determined in what form this appearance was? It's the context. Genesis 17:22, "And when He/God finished talking with him, God went up from Abrahm. In other words, God went straight up north.
I maintain the angel of the Lord who multiplied Hagar's descendants is the same being here at Genesis 17:1-3 that multiplied Abraham's descendants. To back this up, (appearance wise) we have Genesis 18:1. "Now the Lord appeared to him/Abraham by the oaks of Mamre, while he was sitting at the tent door in the heat of the day.
Vs2 says, "behold three men were standing opposite him; and when he saw them, he ran form the tent door to meet them, and bowed himself to the earth." One of the three men was the angel of the Lord, (the preincarnate Jesus Christ) and the other two men were actual angels. This is definitely a physical appearance because at verses 4-5, Abraham offers them water and bread.
From Genesis 18:9-33 a dialogue ensues between the Lord and Abraham regarding the destruction of Sodom and Gomora. At vs33, "And as soon as He/the Lord had finished speaking to Abraham the Lord departed; and Abraham returned to his place. At Genesis 19:1, "Now the TWO ANGELS came to Sodom in the evening as Lot was sitting in the gate of Sodom."
It should be noted Genesis 21:1-2 refers back to Genesis 18 where the Lord is having a discussion with Abraham. "Then the Lord took note of Sarah as He had said, and the Lord did for Sarah as He had promised. Vs2, "So Sarah conceived and bore a son to Abraham in his old age at the appointed time at which time God had spoken to him."
I see Dottard covered Judges 6:12 and Judges 13:3 as referring to a physical appearance of the angle of the Lord/God. Starting at Judges 6:8 it says, "Thus says the Lord, the God of Israel. "It was I who brought you up from Egypt." Please read the rest of the verses/chapter and note vs22. "When Gideon saw that he was the angel of the Lord, he said, "Alas, O Lord God! For now I have seen the angel of the Lord face to face." Vs23, "And the Lord said to him, "Peace to you, do not fear; you shall not die." Remember, Hagar said the same thing at Genesis 16:13.
